# How can I increase the number of particle sprites?

Tags: unity-game-engine, particles, particle-system

I am making a defense game. Since the concept of the game is Christmas, we are using Christmas-specific particles, but since the number of sprites used for particles is so small, we need a way to increase the number of sprites. Is there a way to increase it in a particle system?

I've tried many things in the 'particle system' in the particle inspector to increase the number of particles, but I can only adjust the size.

Answer (score 1):

Double-check that your `Max Particles` count is set to the desired number (default: 1000). If it is, then the settings you're looking for are located in the `Emission` and `Shape` modules of the `Particle System`:

[image: Emission and Shape modules]

By default, the `Rate over Time` is `10` particles per second; you could increase this value to have more particles. Alternatively, you could create `Bursts` of particles instead.

The default `Shape` is a 25-degree-angle `Cone` which faces the Z-axis. Feel free to change the `Shape` and/or the properties like `position` and `scale` to get your desired result.

I would also suggest looking at [Unity Learn: Introduction To Particle Systems](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-particle-systems) if you're new to this system.